# jackson - json parsing not working well

Tags: java, android, json, jackson

In my json example I have a problem and I can't resolve it.

let's pretend I have class City

```
class City {
int id;
int name;
Address address
}
```

Sometimes from server comes address (i.e address_id,address_name ....) but when in particular cases there is no address the server returns false boolean value.

I try to parse jsonObject

```
City city = new ObjectMapper().readValue(response.toString(), City.class);
```

address returning some data and it's okay. but when address returns false boolean value I got this error

`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type from Boolean value`.

Is there any way to fix the problem?

case 1.

```
{
  "isLogin": false,
  "totalSum": 0,
  "addressCount": 0,
  "address": false, 
}
```

case 2.

```
{
  "isLogin": false,
  "totalSum": 378,
  "addressCount": 1,
  "address": {
    "id": "1127",
    "name": "New York",   
}
```

Comment: can you please show the content of your response.toString(); ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jakson is waiting for an adress object not a boolean value.Try to return a null instead of false.

Comment: yes I know but there is no way that I can change any code in server side

Comment: Then you will have to modify the return value before tying to parse it. Removing '"address" : false' from the response entirely should work.

Answer (score 0):

Using a custom deserializer will work here.
You define one for the type City, if first event when reading address is false then you set address to null if it is START_OBJECT you delegate to jackson the deserialization of Address type.